# System will boot but not restart after update

Tags: boot

New user to Linux and Elementary OS. I recently installed updates via the app store. The system will no longer restart. On a shut down the shut down sequence and start sequence are much slower. On a restart it shuts down but the system hangs during the boot sequence. I've tried running Boot Repair and gotten the following report

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rbcCvNNdwH/

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Definitely learned my lesson about not having a system backup!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Grant, have you tried holding down the left shift key from a cold boot - it should show a list of previous builds so you can select the older build. I've have this before and recall it was a video driver issue. Hope this helps!

Comment: It did somewhat seems I've got it booting normally on restart but now it seems to be about 5-10secs slower then it was, thanks for the learning though :)